# Excel VBA error 1004 on PDF export - not a path issue

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, runtime-error

I'm exporting multiple sheets to PDF with the following code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("3rd party", "Dashboard", "BS_3rd")).Select
        
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
         fileName:=PDF_FileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
         IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
         OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

The code works fine with any sheet except "Dashboard". That sheet in any combination (even on its own) causes a

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined

error on the second line. Selection is fine, export to PDF runs into this bug.

Please advise.

Comment: We need to know what it is on "Dashboard" that PDF converter doesn't like. What happens if you go to that sheet from the keyboard and manually try to save it as a PDF? If that works OK then try recording a macro to see what is the difference.

Comment: Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` in the preceding code? Maybe you have an invalid character in PDF_FileName? Could you show us the complete (relevant) code and maybe a screenshot of sheet `Dashboard`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 the path is fine. It exports with all sheets in the workbook except for "Dashboard". And "Dashboard" on its own also gives the error. When I exclude "Dashboard" then no error.

Comment: @MartinBrown the sheet exports fine if done manually. I'll test the macro recording and revert. Thanks.